# How to get group ranking list (rank by member count) from SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables described as so:

> Table Member

```
MemberID | GroupID
1        | 101
2        | 104
3        | 107
4        | 102
5        | 103
6        | 104
7        | 105
8        | 106
......
```

> Table Group (groups are nested)

```
GroupID | ParentID
101     | NULL
102     | NULL
103     | 111
104     | 101
105     | 102
106     | 105
107     | NULL
......
```

Now I want to get **TOP 10** groups having maximum number of members from DB, how can I write my SQL query ?

please note:

1. total members count should contains subgroup members count
2. a group can cantain unlimited level of subgroups (eg. parent -> subLv1 -> subLv2 ...)

For above example, the desired result is:

```
Rank | GroupID | MemberCount
1    | 102     | 3
2    | 101     | 2
3    | 105     | 2
4    | 103     | 1
5    | 104     | 1
....
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample results (and corresponding sample data).

Answer (score 0):

Try this (syntax not fully checked):

```
SELECT GROUP_ID, SUM(Y) AS Z
   FROM ( SELECT GroupID AS GROUP_ID, COUNT(*) AS Y
            FROM MEMBER
          GROUP BY GroupID
          UNION
          SELECT ParentID AS GROUP_ID, COUNT(*) AS Y
            FROM GROUP
          GROUP BY ParentID 
        )
GROUP BY GROUP_ID
ORDER BY Z DESC;
```

Then, you can add a limit to the number of records retrieved.

Comment: TY, but it seems this query require group has only 1 child level ? my group table defines a nested group structure like a tree @FDavidov

Comment: You mean that any node, at any level, should include the total number of children, grandchildren, gran-grandchildren, ...?

Comment: Yes exactly ! It's a difficult task for me. @FDavidov

Comment: Well, since you have no a-priori idea of what the depth of the hierarchy may be, the only alternatives would be: (1) write a recursive query (available in ORACLE and apparently also in SQL-Server) or implement a recursive function. I suggest you try either of the two and re-post this question (with the new solution) or create a new one. Sorry.